# What is the edit command for 64-bit Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, text-editors

I am using Windows 7 64-bit. I could not find a command that enables me to write a text file in the command prompt. Is there a command for this on Windows 7 x64? I tried `edit` but it is not supported by Windows 7 x64. Is there another command to do this?

Comment: Why would you need a console text editor exactly? Is this something related to SQL query composition?

Comment: If you are coming from a nix background, or if you do a lot of work in the console generally it can be really helpful to have a bare-bones text editor - for hacking scripts etc (like vim or nano)...

Comment: `notepad filename.txt` should do the trick, although I freely grant that it's not `edit` and will launch a separate window. (`wordpad`, I believe, is not on the path by default, although you may need to use it if editing *n?x-originated files.)

Comment: As for when this was useful: I believe I used to view Windows shortcut (.lnk) files using `edit`. (I think when the links were broken, Windows couldn't edit them anymore--or maybe I was just curious.) Trying to edit them from within a GUI just followed the shortcut. This still works from the command prompt: `notepad whatever.lnk`.

Answer (score 17):

Execute `copy con note.txt`

and type text, finish with Ctrl-Z.

Comment: Very cool trick that.

Comment: So how do I edit existing 10-MB files?

Answer (score 9):

There is none. `EDIT` is a 16-bit DOS program, and Windows 7 x64 [doesn't support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282423) 16-bit applications. If you need to edit text files via the command line in 64-bit Windows, you will need to use a third party application [like VIM](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a replacement console text editor, [Brief Basic](http://www.briefeditor.com/) is a single `.exe` file and uses pretty standard keyboard shortcuts.

The original 16-bit version of Brief was widely used in the MS-DOS days.

[image: Brief text Editor]

Comment: Brief requires installation; Edit did not; I do not have administrative privileges.

Comment: @Alex Brief does not need installation. It's just a single .exe file that needs to be added to any directory in your `%PATH%`, and any user can edit their user `%PATH%`.

Comment: That might be the case; but, their website's Download link brings me to downloading Brief450.msi , which is pretty obviously an installer.
Hmm, for some reason SU removes the [at]paradroid at the beginning of my text...

Comment: @Alex That's because I get a notification anyway, as the comments are under one of my answers.